# Share article and with short url / short link

Tags: module, plugin, weblinks

If you share a youtube video, youtube automatically create a shortlink that you can send manually, or via a variaty of different social media plattforms. See screenshot:

[image: youtube sharing shortlink]

I've searched for a joomla plugin that does this task, but all I've found are plugins for creating short URLs and other plugins for social media sharing purposes (e.g. [sharethis](http://www.sharethis.com/)). Is there a joomla plugin / module that takes combines both tasks at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a database table to store the relation between articles and their shortlinks, then you would need a plugin to redirect to the correct page via the shortlink that fires before that page gets loaded.

The project itself wouldn't be too hard, and actually gives me a good idea for a new plugin / component set.

Comment: Actually, stackexchange uses this function as well. Just click on the "share" button on any question or answer. Keep us posted if you have a got at this project!

Comment: Will do, you can search for my extensions on the JED as well to see what I have there. Just search for TWCarter.

Answer (score 0):

youtube.be works integrated with Youtube. So, they link the short url with videos at once.

Sharethis or similar sharing services don't generate short Urls for every content item you publish. It's only a widget for your page.

You could implement an [auto-posting](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/social-web/social-share) extension (like [AutoTweetNG](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/social-web/social-share/autotweet-ng)) to generate short urls for every new content item and finally look for a way to show the short url in your content item.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I had a hard time choosing which one to accept, Terry Carter was a bit more specific which is why I chose his answer..